# render item flatlist with array of object in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

New to react native I have this array of objects.
I want to map this data by date with Flatlist. Can anyone help me? Thank You:)

```
const data = {
    '21 Jan 2021': [
      {
        id: 96,
        name: 'Received​ PK19995',
        datetime: '21 Jan 2021 10:00 AM',
        amount: 40,
      },
      {
        id: 95,
        name: 'Received​ PK12355',
        datetime: '21 Jan 2021 9:00 AM',
        amount: 40,
      },
      {
        id: 94,
        name: 'Received PK12333',
        datetime: '21 Jan 2021 8:00 AM',
        amount: 1340,
      },
    ],
    '20 Jan 2021': [
      {
        id: 93,
        name: 'Received​ PK10045',
        datetime: '20 Jan 2021 8:00 AM',
        amount: 40,
      },
    ],
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your data to be able to use it in FlatList like this

```js
const data = {
  '21 Jan 2021': [{
      id: 96,
      name: 'Received​ PK19995',
      datetime: '21 Jan 2021 10:00 AM',
      amount: 40,
    },
    {
      id: 95,
      name: 'Received​ PK12355',
      datetime: '21 Jan 2021 9:00 AM',
      amount: 40,
    },
    {
      id: 94,
      name: 'Received PK12333',
      datetime: '21 Jan 2021 8:00 AM',
      amount: 1340,
    },
  ],
  '20 Jan 2021': [{
    id: 93,
    name: 'Received​ PK10045',
    datetime: '20 Jan 2021 8:00 AM',
    amount: 40,
  }, ],
};

const refinedData = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key].map(v => ({ ...v,
  date: key
}))).flat()

console.log(refinedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to render `datetime` data, you will need to map in the `keyExtractor`, as long as it receives another array, so you can do:

```
return (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList
      data={Object.values(DATA)}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.map(i => i.datetime)}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```